# Scala syntactic sugar for mandatory Option-type function parameters

Tags: scala, syntactic-sugar, scala-option

Is there a syntatic sugar to call a function with multiple parameters of type `Option` but without default value of `None` present in any?

```
def func1(param1: Option[String],
          param2: Option[String]): String =
  param1.getOrElse(param2.getOrElse("none"))

func1(None, None)                      // "none"
func1(Some("value1"), None)            // "value1"
func1(Some("value1"), Some("value2"))  // "value1"
func1(None, Some("value2"))            // "value2"
```

I would like to achieve returned value of `"value2"` by giving only one parameter while calling `func1()` while not giving `None` to any other.

```
func1(param2=Some("value2"))  // not enough arguments for method 
                              //  func1: (param1: Option[String], param2: Option[String])String.
                              //  Unspecified value parameter param1.
```

I'm unable to modify the original function. I could wrap it with another function but looking for already available syntatic sugars first.

Comment: Give both of them default args? You can also do `param1.orElse(param2).getOrElse("none")`

Comment: To expand on erip's comment a little bit: why not just declare `func1` as `def func1(param1: Option[String] = None,
          param2: Option[String] = None): String` ?

Comment: As said, I'm unable to modify the original function (it is from library I'm using and would not like to fork anything at this point). I could wrap it with another function but looking for already available syntatic sugars first.

Comment: You'll have to wrap it. It would be dangerous if you could modify library code, right?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you cannot change the function, that should not be possible.
But since we're in scala you can just add a method that fits your needs via implicit conversions.

Let's say this class is defined in your library:

```
class Foo {
  def func1(param1: Option[String], param2: Option[String]): String =
    param1 orElse param2 getOrElse "none"
}
```

You can create an implicit class that adds your own function with the correct signature.

```
implicit class FooOps(foo: Foo) {
  def func1(param1: Option[String] = None, param2: Option[String] = None): String =
    foo.func1(param1, param2)
}
```

The method can now be invoked as you wanted

```
scala> new Foo().func1()
res1: String = none
```

Comment: Aki's proposal does not work. Any ideas why?
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kA87f12VQsyARwYbO54YTA

Comment: Apparently it only works if you call it with an empty parameter list or if you change the name of the function in your implicit class